# SharePoint 2007 crawler is not stopping

Tags: search, sharepoint-server, sql-server, crawling, sharepoint-farm

I recently tried to start a full crawl after my colleague mentioned that some of the files are not visible in the search.

Normally the crawler start full crawl every week. so i manually tried to start a full crawl. but eventually i come up with error message saying "Could not access the search service configuration database".
[image: Error message while trying to add new scope]

While looking on the content source in search administration area (*Shared Services Administration: SharedServices1 > Search Administration > Content sources*)i found that its being crawling for about 333 hours that's about 14 days.
[image: This image shows that the crawler running more than 330hrs]

So, i though to stop the crawler and start again. but it didn't seems to be stopping from crawling. [image]

Does anyone have any idea to solve this issue... thanks in advance.